# how to transfer file from PC to Windows-mobile and from Windows-mobile to PC?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

i need to transfer `Text.txt` file from PC **(using WebService)**

to Windows-mobile 5.0 - and from Windows-mobile to PC

can i get any sample code in C# for the WebService and the Windows-mobile ?

thanks in advance

Comment: it doesn't work that way - you try something and ask for help - this isn't a 'give me teh codez' site.

Comment: need help.....any direction......from where to start......help....

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly transfer files. you should try ActiveSync RAPI to send information.

Use  OpenNETCF. It's a useful compact framework for WindowsMobile (.NET).

Try this:

```
    string fileToSendToDevice = @"C:\Text.txt";

    OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI rApi = new OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication.RAPI();

    if (!rApi.DevicePresent) return; // no active sync
    if (!rApi.Connected) rApi.Connect();

    if (!File.Exists(fileToSendToDevice)) return; // file not found

    rApi.CopyFileToDevice(fileToSendToDevice,
        Path.Combine(@"\My Documents\", Path.GetFileName(fileToSendToDevice)));
```

Comment: thanks for the help !. i know to work with RAPI, i need to transfer file Through WIFI  (not Through ActiveSync)

Comment: Then you probably have to think simply, just open a socket to the server, and send the file content. Because the Compact Framework does not offer too much functionalities, but at least, you can always open a tcp/ip socket and send data trough it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure CF supports both webservices (2.0 onwards I think) and WCF (3.5 onwards).

Answer (score 1):

The concept is really no different than PC-to-PC if you intend to use a Web Service for the transfer (assuming the Web Service is running on the PC).  Find any example on the web that transfers a file to and from a Web Service and it will likely be applicable.

If you then have a question that is more specific to WinMo/CF or an implementation problem, feel free to update this question about what you've tried and what about it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

One of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164240.aspx#S7) [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446547.aspx) examples will probably help. The code for the PC will be likely the same if not simpler.

Then you just need to write the web service.